# Header file not found in DemoTests?

Tags: ios, xcode6

I have add google map framework in xcode.
When I added GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h framework in appdelegate.h or .m it works well.
also when I added this framework viewcontroller.h and .m it works.

but when I tried to import this framework in 
DemoGoogleMapTests.m it gives error "GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h" file not found.

appreciate for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because `DemoGoogleMapTests.m` did not same Target with `appdelegate.h` and `viewcontroller.h` or .m

It's may belong target DemoGoogleMapTests. So need to change it's target build settings `"Framework Search Paths"` to add search path for `GoogleMaps`